# change a property of an object if the current time exceeds time + 30 seconds - javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, ecmascript-6, lodash

I currently have the following:

```
let time = Date.now()
```

I need to change a property of an object if the current time exceeds  `time + 30 seconds`. I need to make this check every 10 seconds.

```
let obj = {
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    has30secExceeded: true or false
}
```

The property I need to set is has30secExceeded. What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this running on the browser or the backend?  What do you want to happen when 30 seconds is exceeded?

Comment: use setInterval to check that every 10s and change its property according to that

Comment: You mean that you want to change the property if `obj.timestamp` > `time`+ 30 seconds?

Comment: You've got a fine answer here, but I will say this strikes me as a weird thing to do. What code is checking this flag, and how does it know to run? Since it is just a flag, this means you are just polling, which is usually frowned upon for JS in favor of explicit events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` which accepts a callback and a millisecond delay. Keep in mind that `setInterval` only schedules the event to be pushed on to the queue at the interval, which mean it may not be called at that exact interval.

```
let originalTime = Date.now()

let obj = {
    has30secExceeded:false
}
setInterval(()=>{
  obj.timestamp = Date.now();
  if(Date.now() > originalTime + 3000){
    obj.has30secExceeded = true;
  }
},10000);
```